# std::uniform_real_distribution always returns infinity

Tags: c++, random, numeric-limits

When I run this code:

```
double getRandomDouble() {
    static std::mt19937 entropy_ = std::mt19937();
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution;
    distribution.param(typename decltype(distribution)::param_type(std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(),
                                                                   std::numeric_limits<double>::max()));
    return distribution(entropy_);
}
```

It always returns infinity (at least in GCC8.1 & clang 11.0.1. In MSVC 14.16.27023 it asserts)

[Here is a working demonstration in GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLpNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRAA2UgAdUCwuto9QxMzb19/Ohs7RyMXN08lFTU6BgJmYgIg41NOc0TMVQDU9IIoh2dXD0U0jKyQ3OqSspi4jwBKRVQDYmQOAHIAegGAagAVAE8vTGHxruJhtCxhhFdMUmGSYdZUZnRhkWHMAA9mIy92ADpxAAYAQSkAZltkQyXxB51iEXRUI3fsG73SRPWgvAxvD7qBQEYiYU7/QGAn4GJzsYbATAEABK31%2BABEuqjMBA2sNxAB2WR3YY04bQ5hqZB0gjoEAgIwETgATi5D3Jh3oxFQXnGAH0yQ88czWezOTy%2BST3lTbrTpWyDLQ8DRiEZRbC2KL8NDiHgnAZkrR3jpkUT/sMjTDTeaAkrAaqHSazRaLl50qcIARJlpTtMsC9A1MIB6nRa2mzfV9dRHidCZbRjK48MhRaw8EZCAorTb2P82dsAO6YaEk9Zu1X1huNpvNlut2mptnpoyZ7O5/MEQsfYuYUvs5hHEltNqu6m02EEbq0e14Y0xgIQLQw4Vi6cPZUUvGIu62AjDIzMWyKu4U5Wq7XDCAn4Z4CVS65K58SnTDTjvvdkmQ5DwUkbzrBsOxQLpTytK0AMkHFtF%2BYYu1aOCv1gjFsVxIwCRRdgSXQj44PEABWHRLUkSQZxVWkDzA4Z50XYY/33ck8T6DpWBAPoSL6UhTD6a4%2BNQbidDkOQ6TmXoAIeTg%2BIIbihKnUgAGsQBI64hG47g%2BIEoTSBEvo%2BIUEBNIUwSONIOBYBgRBILOPB2DICgIDQBynJQYRRE4X9OFIKhHIIVwTIgJxFL4pxbHScZuLk0g3O7egAHlaFYGKLNILBz1EdhwsyvBYUKAA3Ks8uOApzX6fST2UPLcycL5iHGPQsDyx0jFiyyaHoJg2A4Hh%2BEELyxHEmQhFNEzIA6YULRMvoAFp5tTd48QkQCZEkfT8kKDQN20OocgsbRmgqNw/J8PwLQOwQLoiWgTtiSo/O2i1ilqfRskEF6ihqUpbHKR6zsad7gkO%2BkMge1pOA6BQpP6zjuN4/i8sMo4AA53Hm9xuAWYaf04C5rguTgH1wQhNkePzhj0dzXBk6HqdG6R5PC5S1I0rS%2Bh00gOvcAnrhIvmBaFwXfxI5GMsM4zTNIcylKs2yICQKCvHNchKDcrxHKeix8CIIHusYFhcoG8svi8TqEZ43SUe4ynhnLQgEGGdHMex3GRGAfHCeJlmLOUlZdkqGsuK5viOoeNGLi5bhI5juPY7Rrlxb04TuOlszWY6dnNNDh4bcl9PZazznJAL/SpeL/2OhK4g/A0bggA)

I would expect this function to return any random double value, what is happening here?

Comment: change `lowest()` to `min()`

Comment: @TedLyngmo but then it won't do what I want it to, as it will only return positive values...

Comment: Ah... ok, `-max()/2.0, max()/2.0` could perhaps be a good range then. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/hYoqedEor)

Comment: @TedLyngmo While this may "fix" the issue, it still doesn't explain what is going on...

Comment: I made the `prng()` function in the example that is returning a `static` (`thread_local`) PRNG so that you don't get the same number every time. Btw, you could use `lowest() / 2.0` instead.

Comment: From [rand.dist.uni.real#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/rand.dist.uni.real#1) `p(x|a,b)=1/(b−a)`, but `max()-lowest()` make the result problematic :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The choice of parameters violates the precondition of `std::uniform_real_distribution` (c.f. [§26.6.9.2.2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/rand.dist.uni.real#2)).

The preconditions being `a ≤ b` and `b - a ≤ numeric_limits<T>::max()`, where `a` and `b` are the min and max of the distribution. Using `numeric_limits<double>::lowest()` and `numeric_limits<double>::max()` would go against this.

As suggested by [Ted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66854143/stduniform-real-distribution-always-returns-infinity#comment118175858_66854143), using `a = -max()/2.0`, `b = max()/2.0` would be a better choice.

Comment: `[0; max) * randomSign` might be more appropriate to have "whole" double's range.

Answer (score 1):

The mandated implementation of `uniform_real_distribution` is basically distribute uniformly in `[0,1)` then map to `[a,b)` by multiplying by `(b-a)` and then adding `a`.

It is a fine speed-oriented implementation, but when applied to extreme cases it fails. In your case computing `b-a` results in infinity and subsequently the whole computation fails.

Comment: So this is a bug with the compiler implementations?

Comment: @Troyseph I believe this is mandated by the C++ standart. That proposal had a couple of bugs. In general, I am not sure if this issue one can call a bug because only in very odd circumstances one needs random numbers over the whole range of doubles and it requires a lot of extra computations and verification to ensure that it works properly. Which will just slow down the program needlessly for vast majority of users.

Answer (score -1):

You have a numeric problem: the distribution is using a probability function: `1 / (b - a)`, and in this case `b - a` is out of the range of a `double` (which means `inf`, therefore all the numbers are `inf`). You can fix it by lowering the limits as in the example below.

In addition, you are always using a new random number generator, and, as the seed is the same, it is always generating the same number. You can either make your generator external to the function so it continues generating new numbers, or better, associate a random device.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

double getRandomDouble() {
    std::random_device rd; // <<
    std::mt19937 entropy_ = std::mt19937(rd()); // <<
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution;

    using param = typename decltype(distribution)::param_type;
    distribution.param(param(std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest() / 2, 
                             std::numeric_limits<double>::max() / 2));
    return distribution(entropy_);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Random number: " << getRandomDouble() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can test it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4b3Gqx7TM).

Comment: Updated the GodBolt, this is not the issue, it still always returns infinity

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TbTeosdMs) of your code with `lowest` instead of `min` as OP. -> inf

Comment: Isn't "the range [-1, 1] multiplied by `max`" going to lose a lot of granularity?